# Sharepoint selectors in Central Administration don't work in IE 6 on the server VM (MOSS 2007)

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-6

Sharepoint Central Administration site uses the selector control I'm talking about a lot (for selecting site collections and web applications primarily)

[image: sharepoint selector control]

I have MOSS 2007 installed on a VM. When I open Central Administration from outside the VM from my desktop everything works fine. But when I open it from IE 6 installed on the VM the selectors just won't open the popup, when I click on them and there seems to be no javascript errors.

I suppose it has something to do with the configuration of the browser on the VM but I don't know what exactly to look for.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

@Edit: I have solved this problem by installing IE7 on the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Are you using IE6 on your desktop? Or IE7?

The way I got around it was using IE7 on my desktop.